# text to speech [TTS] TTSPlaybackCreate unable to initialize dynamics: -3000

Tags: iphone, swift, avfoundation

```
@IBAction func btnclicked(_ sender: Any) {
        print("clicked")
        let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "Hello world")
        utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-GB")
        utterance.rate = 0.1

        let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
        synthesizer.speak(utterance)
    }
```

//I am getting this "[TTS] TTSPlaybackCreate unable to initialize dynamics: -3000"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, that log message doesn't mean that you have done something wrong, but in this case your `AVSpeechSynthesizer` is going out of scope and will be deallocated, probably silencing your output. You should assign the `AVSpeechSynthesizer` to a class instance variable to prolong its lifetime.

Comment: any solution for that ??

Comment: For the log message or for the deallocation?

Comment: for deallocation

Comment: yes, turn `synthesizer` into a class member variable instead. right now it's a local variable and it's going out of scope